# Extracting field value in QGIS graphical model | upslope area

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

How to extract latitude and longitude from a point shape file and feed into an algorithm within a single graphical model.
In QGIS graphical model, I need to execute 'upslope area' algorithm for which we need to provide 'x coordinate' and 'y coordinate' which is to be extracted from another algorithm output.

[image]

Comment: You need to use the field calculator to extract X & Y from your point and use these algorithm outputs as input fro the upslope-tool.

Comment: field calculator giving an output in layer form, but upslope taking the input in float form

Comment: You can fetch value of an attribute from a feature from a layer using expressions. A combination of get_feature() and attribute() should work. https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#get-feature-by-id